# How to get rid of scroll bar in fullcalendar 2.2.5 using firefox?

Tags: fullcalendar

A scroll bar appears on fullcalendar 2.2.5 while using firefox when you decrease the size of the window under about 475px. It doesn't happen while using Chrome. So far only checked this running on Linux.  Is there anyway to get rid of the scroll bar? 
Thanks. 
example on http://fullcalendar.io/  just decrease your window size on firefox.